# 502 Bad Gateway for Laravel 5.4 with nginx and php7.0-fpm in Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5

I have my `Laravel 5.4` app setup in `Ubuntu 16.04` server with `nginx` and `php7.0-fpm`, it gives

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

Nginx virtualhost config,

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/html/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        include                  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Tried the following but still not working,

Changed `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;` to `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Changed `try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Restarted service after each change,

```
service nginx restart
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

I can access only the main route with this config,

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/html/laravel/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: For me it was pointing to wrong fpm socket. I had to change `php7.0-fpm` to `php7.2-fpm`.

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was done by restarting the PHP and NGINX service. `systemctl restart nginx.service` & `systemctl restart php8.1-fpm.service`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Updating one line with default php based config worked,

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/html/laravel/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Here changed `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Comment: I have an error message, `nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:16` please help.

Answer (score 13):

First install: `sudo apt install php-fpm`

Then check `/etc/php/7.4/fpm` , Make sure your version of php**7.0**-fpm.sock, php**7.4**-fpm.sock or **7.x**

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case

1. I changed the owner of my project folder to www-data:
   $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./my_project_folder
2. And then changed the user of nginx itself in nginx.conf file /etc/nginx/(it depends on your nginx version)

and it worked for me.